# url not encoded s3 getSignedUrl

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get my file url from a nodejs code

let say my file key is `folder/my%20file.pdf`

I run

```
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {Bucket: 'my-bucket', Key: 'folder/my%20file.pdf'})
```

The result will be `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/my%20file.pdf`

But If I am going to this url I will have

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>0FM7B95PBAKXN424</RequestId>
    <HostId>/7Jcy+pH4IKcJmEAIpAB+XzsrQoX2liF3m+8zM6S1DFGO3nXO+CbxM/3poc771SCttqeR5I3Rd4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

The correct url is `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/my%2520file.pdf`

Comment: What about generating for `Key: 'folder/my file.pdf'`

Comment: `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/my%20file.pdf` is not the signed url.

Comment: @Marcin This is the result I have from `s3.getSignedUrl`

Comment: Please check again. The url should be `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/my%2520file.pdf?<bunch-of-ther-paramters>`.